# path(in:) not being called in expected order

Tags: swift, swiftui, control-flow

I have a shape that needs to be drawn but is not being drawn correctly because of the order of execution.. So I will present this problem in a generic way to get a high level understanding from anyone that answers..

I have a `Shape` which has:

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
   ...
   for drawing in drawings {
     path.move(to: ...)
   }
}
```

So every time a `drawing` is appended to this array.. then I thought that this `path(in:)` would be called but the flow actually happens like this..

1. On my view is

`@State private var drawings: [Drawing] = []`

and I have a function with multiple executions.. one of those executions is `drawing.append(drawing)`

At this point I thought the flow would go back to `path(in:)` but it does not, rather the rest of the function executes.. Why?

Maybe the question should be **When is path(in:) called?**

The next step will be to separate the executions into simpler functions.. but hoping to get some explanation / understanding.

*Updating with reproducible code*

Anyone looking to actually see the code, it is [here](https://gist.github.com/bostshakur/e34f2e550c5015623f7c9748d387b9b8)

*Tried to reduce it to be as minimal as possible*

Expected Behavior:

1. Hit the `-` button and a horizontal line appears
2. hit the `|` button and it forms a right angle with the previous line

So the problem here is that when the user hits the `|` button it makes a diagonal line because the state is changing before I want it to.. please see the function `verticalAssignment()` . Everything inside of the `dispatchQueue` was my attempt to separate the control flow..

If that function fully executes before `line 49` of `WiringDiagram` then I think that's what causes this problem

3. Continue hitting buttons until a square is made.

Comment: It is better to provide working demo code.

Comment: @Asperi I just made an edit giving some reproducible code and explanation of what I've found

Comment: Why are you using dispatch queues in this code? It seems like it is most likely the culprit and I can’t figure out why they are necessary

Comment: @jnpdx I thought I had a data racing issue at first but that's not the case, I kept them there to distinguish to anyone who looked at this code where I thought the control flow issue was.

Comment: Isn’t that the spot that you said is problematic?

Comment: yes, I agree, its unnecessary

Comment: @SergioBost did the other question end up answering this one? If so, you could close this question.

Comment: @jnpdx yes, once I get back home I will, I don’t see a way on the Mobile